# iOS Swift: Could not cast value type '__NSCFNumber' to 'NSString'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am retrieving a number value from my Firebase database (JSON db) and then displaying this number into a `textField`, although I get this error when I try to display it.

> Could not cast value type '__NSCFNumber' to 'NSString'

How can I properly convert the retrieved value to a String, taking into consideration that this value maybe change between a String and a Number when I retrieve it.

Here is my code:

```
let quantity = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "quantity").value // Get value from Firebase

// Check if the quantity exists, then add to object as string.
if (!(quantity is NSNull) && ((quantity as! String) != "")) {
    newDetail.setQuantity(quantity: quantity as! String)
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The error is saying that your quantity is `Number` and you cannot directly convert number to `String`, try like this.

```
newDetail.setQuantity(quantity: "\(quantity)")
```

Or

```
if let quantity = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "quantity").value as? NSNumber {
     newDetail.setQuantity(quantity: quantity.stringValue)
}
else if let quantity = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "quantity").value as? String {
     newDetail.setQuantity(quantity: quantity)
}
```

Or With Single if statement

```
if let quantity = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "quantity").value,
   (num is NSNumber || num is String) {
     newDetail.setQuantity(quantity: "\(quantity))
}
```

Using second and third option there is no need to check for nil.

Comment: can't we use `.description` ?

Comment: The second option works, although not when the quantity value is a String value to begin with. Is there an `else if` statement I could use to check if the value is a String?

Comment: Great, thanks! Both this answer and the one above work, which one do I select as the answer?

Comment: i personally suggest you to mark Nirav D's answer as accepted, It is the absolute approach to achieve the solution.

Comment: @NiravD you nailed it with the third option! Cheers

Comment: Turns out the third option I have to check for Null otherwise it outputs `"<null>"`. That's not a biggy though

Comment: @NiravD I get a warning in xCode that `Comparing a non-optional value of type 'Any' to nil always returns true`

Comment: @n00bAppDev Try to use edited answer , if it still return <null> then it means in response you are getting `<null>` as string.

Comment: Bang on mate! Thanks!

Comment: @n00bAppDev Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 4:**

```
let rollNumber:String = String(format: "%@", rollNumberWhichIsANumber as! CVarArg)
```

Answer (score 4):

You may convert your NSNumber value to string like this too, its more traditional and basic approach to format a string

```
 newDetail.setQuantity(String(format: "%@", quantity))
```

Comment: This works perfect too! I just encapsulated this in my check if Null. Thanks!

Comment: You have already checked for will value so and was correct so didn't bother to write it again.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel There is no need to use `NSString(format:)` you can use `String(format:)` for that.

Comment: Yes Nirav D correct. I wrote this traditional approach may be helpful to people who are trying to migrate from Obj- C to swift.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.

```
 newDetail.setQuantity(String(describing: rollNumberWhichIsANumber))
```

Comment: Be careful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847788/swift-4-could-not-cast-value-of-type-nscfnumber-to-nsstring

Answer (score 0):

In swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1

newDetail.setQuantity(quantity: "(quantity)")

We can convert to string like this **"\(quantity)"**

Answer (score 0):

```
let session_id  : Int32 = (jsonObject.value(forKey: "id") as! NSNumber).int32Value
```

Comment: please write some explanation along with the code. code only answers are generally discouraged in SO --Review

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5:

I manage to fix it buy using `.description` when interpolating the UserDefaults value into a label converting from Int to String.

working code
`highScoreLabel?.text = "HiScore: \(hiScoreValue.description)"`

old code
`highScoreLabel?.text = "HiScore: \(String(describing: hiScoreValue))"`