# Unable to convert anyObject to String

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to run the following code, but am unable to convert the rest.value without the preceeding "Optional".  The following is the code I get when attempting to solve the issue:

```
//for Withdrawl children
    transRef.child("Withdraw").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        //creates enumerator of the snapshot children for
        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
            let curString = (rest.value) as! String
            self.anArray.append(curString)

            //printing the rest.value to make sure there are children to iterate through
            print(rest.value)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData() //<<<<<<<<<<<< RELOAD TABLEVIEW
    })
```

this is the error I am receiving: `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10d068368) to 'NSString'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Swift: Could not cast value type '\_\_NSCFNumber' to 'NSString'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40798220/ios-swift-could-not-cast-value-type-nscfnumber-to-nsstring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Firebase documentation the value property: "Returns the contents of this data snapshot as native types. Data types returned: + NSDictionary + NSArray + NSNumber (also includes booleans) + NSString".

The var returns an Any? in order to handle this versatility.

In this case it looks like it is returning an NSNumber, so the String cast fails. I'm not sure exactly the context of the value in this scenario, but if you are sure that it is going to return a number every time you could cast it to a numerical type (Swift/Objective-C bridging allows NSNumber to be casted to any of the primitive number types in Swift), and then pass it into a String initializer to get a String out of it. e.g.:

```
let curNumber = rest.value as! Double
let curString = String(curNumber)
```

If you aren't sure what type will be returned, but are expecting to put it into an Array of Strings then you should probably check before you cast e.g.:

```
if let curNumber = rest.value as? Double {
   let curString = String(curNumber)
   self.anArray.append(curString)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `(rest.value) as! String`, say [Swift 2] `String(rest.value)` or [Swift 3] `String(describing:rest.value)`. [If `rest.value` is an Optional, then say `rest.value!` in those formulations.]