# swift 3.0 Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10ba54590) to 'NSString' (0x10b060c60)

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift3, option-type

Optional value how to convert string
[image]

output :- Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10ba54590) to 'NSString' (0x10b060c60).
Printing description of sucess:
▿ Optional

Comment: @Dev_Tandel not working any other example

Comment: what problem you are facing ?

Comment: see @NiravD's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40798263/3548469

Comment: from your pic, your success is not string and your are forcing it into one, Hence you are getting crash.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel yes success is int value  how to convert string?

Comment: var myString = String(INTVALUE) @JayprakashSingh

Comment: let myString = String(format: "%d", sucess) //for int or let myString = String(format: "%@", sucess) // for Number