# Swift 4: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' to 'NSString'

Tags: swift, xcode

I have tried

```
self.adc_role_id = String(res["adc_role_id"])

self.adc_role_id = "\(res["adc_role_id']"

self.adc_role_id = (\(res["adc_role_id"] as? String)!
```

but still get

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' to 'NSString'

[image]

I added the dump of res[4] below

As new as I am to Swift, I don't know anything else to try

Comment: In Swift 4, the String initializer requires the `describing` argument label. I don't know if this will solve your problem, but your first line of code should be written: `self.adc_role_id = String(describing: res["adc_role_id"])`

Comment: Mike, that worked like a charm! Thank you!!

Comment: If the id in your data is a number, why store it as a string in your code?

Comment: @jgravois If `res["adc_role_id"]` is already typed as NSNumber then just use its `stringValue` property. Otherwise cast it first to NSNumber then use the property. You could also cast the NSNumber to Int, then use `String()` to make the Int into a string (without using `describing:` because it's not its purpose).

Comment: @Moritz From the docs: Use this initializer to convert an instance of any type to its preferred representation as a String instance.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Yes. And think about what you're reading and its meaning, please. Using `describing:` will use a cascade of options where most of them could lead to unexpected results. For example, it can use `debugDescription` which, often, will *not* represent the string itself. That's why this initializer is called "describing" because it *describes* the string, it doesn't represent it as it is. To create a faithful string you should do just that, use the `String()` initializer, after having done other steps, as I describe in my previous comment. It is not safe at all to use `describing:`.

Comment: Mike's answer is wrong, I've made an answer with explanations and solutions. Note that vadian's answer is also good. In the end you should use what you want except `String(describing:)` because it's definitely not the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift 4, the String initializer requires the `describing:` argument label.

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but your first line of code should be written:

```
self.adc_role_id = String(describing: res["adc_role_id"])
```

Comment: @Moritz explains in his answer why this is not the right way to do this. It may work in some cases, but there are also cases where it will not. Please mark his (or vadian's) as the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry Mike, but the Big Guys are right, even it seems a solution to silence the warning, actually it could cause problems

Answer (score 4):

In your screenshot we can see that `res["adc_role_id"]` is an NSNumber.

To transform an NSNumber to a String you should use its `stringValue` property.

And since a dictionary gives an Optional, you should use optional binding to safely unwrap it.

Example:

```
if let val = res["adc_role_id"] {
    self.adc_role_id = val.stringValue
}
```

You could also, if you want, use string interpolation instead of the property:

```
if let val = res["adc_role_id"] {
    self.adc_role_id = "\(val)"
}
```

but I think using the property is more relevant.

If for some reason the compiler complains about the type of the content, cast it:

```
if let val = res["adc_role_id"] as? NSNumber {
    self.adc_role_id = val.stringValue
}
```

Note that you should *not* use `String(describing:)` because this initializer will try to represent the string in many ways, and some of them will give inaccurate and unexpected results (for example, if `String(describing:)` resolves to use the `debugDescription` property, as explained in the documentation, you may get a totally different string than the one you want).

It's also worth noting that using `String(describing:)` with an optional value such as your dictionary will resolve to a wrong string: `String(describing: res["adc_role_id"])` will give `Optional(yourNumber)`! This is why Mike's answer is wrong. Be careful about this. My advice is to avoid using `String(describing:)` altogether unless for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear and the dump is clear, too.

The value is not a `String`, it's an `Int(64)` wrapped in `NSNumber`

Optional bind the value directly to `Int` (`NSNumber` is implicit bridged to `Int`) and use the `String` initializer.

```
if let roleID = res["adc_role_id"] as? Int {
    self.adc_role_id = String(roleID)
}
```

Please conform to the naming convention that variable names are *camelCased* rather than *snake_cased*

Comment: Clean and correct, this works best as I see